# Using the itemize environment inside a caption

Tags: floats, lists, captions, itemize

The following code does not compile. However, if I remove the `itemize` environment it does. I googled for this problem, and found suggestions that using the caption package would solve the problem, though I did not find any clear description of why the problem occurred in the first place. See for example

http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=8774

I'm using Debian squeeze with TeX Live 2009-11. The included version of `caption` has

```
\ProvidesPackage{caption}[2009/10/09 v3.1k Customizing captions (AR)]
```

I also tried downloading and using the `caption` package from

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/

but this doesn't change anything. I put the sty files in my current directory. I assume that overrides the system files. This one corresponds to

```
\ProvidesPackage{caption}[2010/01/09 v3.1m Customizing captions (AR)]
```

Error message and example file follow.

```
*******************************************    
ERROR: Argument of \@caption has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13     }

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
******************************************************

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
    \caption
    {
      foo
      \begin{itemize}
      \item bar
      \end{itemize}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is described in the caption package documentation, section 3.1 "Typesetting captions". Look out there for "fragile", "robust", and "into a horizontal box to determine the width of the caption".

Comment: I see that entry. The itemize environment causes problems with tex putting the caption text "into a horizontal box to determine the width of the caption", then? Or is the problem something else?

Comment: Yes. If in doubt one can try it out by typesetting the stuff outside a \caption, but within a \hbox instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the `caption` manual:

> If you want to typeset something
> special (like a tabular) as caption,
> you need to give an optional argument
> to `\caption` or `\captionof` for the
> List of Figures or List of Tables,
> too, even if you don’t use such list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\caption[foo bar]{foo
  \begin{itemize}
    \item bar
  \end{itemize}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Addendum #1: As an alternative for using the optional argument of \caption, one can specify the caption package option `list=off` if no lists of floating environments (like "List of Figures") are used.

Comment: Thanks Leo and Axel. I see this argument is used in the latex community example, but I didn't realize it was necessary. Can anyone explain why this problem occurs in the first place? Axel, not clear what a list of floating environments would look like.

Comment: Damn, I see the first entry in the errors subsection has exactly this error, with the solution.

Comment: What does "resp." mean here? I don't understand what `foo` and `bar` are here either. They're not command, so what are they?

Comment: @Miguel names (here: `foo bar`) within the squared brackets after \caption will list this figure/table in the list of figures/tables. Leaving name empty removes this instance from the list of instances. I filed a change request to `name in list of figures`.

Comment: @Migwell  "resp." is just Denglisch for "or". It indicates that the author of the `caption` manual must have been a native German speaker.  It's something you often see when people have tried (and, frankly, failed) to translate the German *bzw.* (which stands for *beziehungsweise*) into English.

Comment: Note the `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}`. I had the optional argument to `\caption` but that alone is not enough.

Comment: As of 3/15/2024, the [package docs](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf) do not say "resp." or anything else like that. I have submitted an edit request to fix this confusing wording; personally, I immediately clicked back on my browser the first three or four times I ended up on this page because the given answer seemed like incoherent gibberish or technical-ese way above my paygrade (FYI, "resp." in standard English stands for "respective").