# Caption without text below "Figure''

Tags: captions, indentation

I have a problem with captions.

I'm new to LaTeX and I don't know English names of "this". I want to have something like:

```
Figure X.X: bla bla bla bla

            bla bla bla bla

            etc.
```

and

```
Figure X.X: bla bla bla bla 

            a) bla bla bla 

            b) bla bla bla
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `caption` package with the option `format=hang` to do this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{20pt}{10pt} %just for demonstration
    \caption{ Here's a long caption, it goes across more than
    one line| the style you describe is called `hanging'.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Putting an `enumerate` environment in a caption can be done- see

[Using the itemize environment inside a caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10551/using-the-itemize-environment-inside-a-caption)

for details.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=colon]{caption}    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{5cm}{3cm} %just for demonstration
    \caption[text for the list of figures]
            { \tabular[t]{@{}p{5cm}@{}}
              bla bla bla bla and some other nonsense text \\
              a) bla bla bla    \\
              b) bla bla bla
              \endtabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hanging indent is the default setup for captions in the classes from the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle.

```
\documentclass[paper=letter]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \rule{3.2in}{1.8in}
    \caption[LoF entry]{\lipsum[1]}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```