# Using enumerate environment in a figure caption

Tags: captions, environments, enumerate, subfloats

I'm trying to create an inline list into a figure caption like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}
\item Item X
\item Item Y and
\item Item Z
\end{enumerate*}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\centering
\subfloat{}
\subfloat{}
\subfloat{}
\caption{
Here I want the enumerate
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Item X
\item Item Y and
\item Item Z
\end{enumerate*}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10551/using-the-itemize-environment-inside-a-caption), but I got the following error:

```
Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. }
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: No problem if you add an optional argument of `\caption` without the list.

Comment: This is precisely the same issue as the one in the question you linked to. And, as Bernard's comment says, has also the same solution. Did you get the point of Leo Liu's answer?

Comment: You really don't need `\subfloat` or `subfig` here. If you're using a single caption, you don't need sub-figures.

Comment: Make sure that you delete generated files before recompiling after adding the optional argument e.g. `.lof`, `.aux` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as

```
\caption[]{
Here I want the enumerate
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Item X
\item Item Y and
\item Item Z
\end{enumerate*}
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you've done here and why it works. That should not take too long, but improves the answer a lot.

Comment: The side effects of this must be mentioned by the community member who answered this. This removes the corresponding figure's entry from the list of figures for the document.

Comment: @Krishna Yes, it affects the "LOF", thanks for pointing out...